# Getting error process has died for rplidar A2M8

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, lidar

Im trying to run rviz on my raspberry pi.
Via SSH im connecting to my RP which has the rplidar connected. Im not sure if the lidars are defect, however while using a new one, i dont get the error message.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem here and how i can solve it?

["defect" RPLidar A2M8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujWsm.png)

["defect" RPLidar A1M8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBzHu.png)

[new RPLidar A2M8 from a friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0VDN.png)

The firmware seems to be a different one, can i upgrade it in any way? Im working on Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS and ROSserial

I tried to update the firmware, but couldn't find anything i can use

Comment: When trying to locate the log file, it doesnt create anything at all

Comment: Does this lidar have a config you can update? If not, firmware does appear to be the issue. Notice your output has an invalid scan mode, and what appears to be a spin rate that's an overflown(or uninitialized int).

Comment: I tried to update the firmware. But u cant find anything about it. Do you have an idea where i can get the firmware for a slamtec rplidar A2M8 R3?